# .htaccess file is protecting all of my directories. How can I allow access to one?

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a folder on my server called dvd and I've put an index file in this folder. If i go directly to /dvd/index.html I can view the file. However, if I go only to /dvd/ I get a 403 forbidden error. I'm sure I can allow access to the /dvd/ folder but I can't figure out how. Below is the filesmatch code i'm using at the moment. Can someone please tell me what it is I'm supposed to be doing? Thanks

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

DirectoryIndex index.html

to the .htaccess, seems like it's not set if you can view it directly.

Comment: do i add this into the filesmatch tag?

Comment: turns out there was a similar tag to that already on the page but it was asking for index.php. simply changed the name of my file to index.php. thanks!